# How do I get check columns for a specific value in Google Apps Script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet that manually gets updated with names. I set a trigger that activates the function whenever the spreadsheet gets edited. I want the function to check the range D1:D500 for the name "John". If a cell contains that value it should send an email. I haven't written code in over 2 years so I'm very rusty. I'm not quite sure what I did wrong here. I think messed up the array.

```
function CheckMail() {
  var mailRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("October").getRange("D1:D500"); 
  var data = mailRange.getValue();
  var dataLength = data.length;
  for(var i=0;i<dataLength;i++){
      if(data[i][1] == "John") {
         var emailAddress = "myemail@gmail.com"
         var message = 'New parcel for ' + data[i][1];
         var subject = 'New parcel';
         MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: Try using `mailRange.getValues();`. Plural instead of singular.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to accomplish your needs you can use the following code:

```js
function CheckMail() {
  var mailRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("October").getRange("D1:D500");
  var data = mailRange.getValues();
  var dataLength = data.length;
  for (var i=0; i<dataLength; i++) {
    if (data[i][0] == "John") {
       var emailAddress = "myemail@gmail.com"
       var message = 'New parcel for ' + data[i][0];
       var subject = 'New parcel';
       MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
    }
  }
}
```

The main differences are:

1. Usage of [`getValues()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValues()) instead of [`getValue()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValue()). Notice that `getValue()` only returns the value of the top-left cell in the range that you have, whereas `getValues()` returns a matrix containing all the values in the range.
2. Accessing the element using `data[i][0]` instead of `data[i][1]`. Although cells and rows are indeed 1-indexed, arrays in GAS are 0-indexed.

Additionally to this, the current code will check whether the value in the cell matches exactly John. Other options would be:

- Checking whether the name **contains** "John". In this case, you should replace the condition in the *if statement* from `data[i][0] == "John"` to `data[i][0].indexOf("John") > -1`.
- Checking whether the name **starts with** "John". In this case, you should replace the condition in the *if statement* from `data[i][0] == "John"` to `data[i][0].indexOf("John") == 0`.

Answer (score -1):

What ross shared in the comment - using `getValues` (plural) instead of `getValue` +

You also **do not need** `data[i][1]` <strike>(2D Array)</strike> as you're fetching a single column of data :)

Try this -

```
function CheckMail() {
  var mailRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("October").getRange("D1:D500"); 
  var data = mailRange.getValues();
  var dataLength = data.length;
  for(var i=0;i<dataLength;i++){
    if(data[i] == "John") {
      Logger.log("Got John")
    }
  }
}
```

You can replace the **Logger** and run any other code, as required. Hope this helps!

Edit: Removing my rationale for why `data[i][1]` may not work

Comment: Actually `getValues()` always returns a 2-d array as mentioned in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValues()), I believe you will still need to use `data[i][1]`.

Comment: @ross - the code that I've shared works without `data[i][1]` & spits out `undefined` if used using it; perhaps my reasoning for it is wrong :)

Comment: @ross is right. You should use `data[i][0]` as  array indexes start with 0 and there's only one element in `data[i]`(as you're fetching a single column D:D);so, the second element `data[i][1]` is `undefined`